# How to watch directory and output source maps for different folder in Coffeescript?

Tags: coffeescript

```
coffee -mo js/ -cw coffeescript
```

The command above is what I did, but it gives me an error when the `.coffee` script changes

```
[1]    46385 bus error  coffee -mo js/ -cw coffeescript
```

How to do it correctly?

Comment: I can't reproduce it. The command you gave, works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a look at [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/), which is a build system for JavaScript. It provides CoffeeScript interpretation and many other useful features, such as file watcher.